# php, codeigniter - How to pass a variable containing array as its value into a checkbox's value field

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's a piece of my view ( codeigniter ) :

```
<?php 
echo form_open('main/req_submit');
foreach($start as $mediator){
    echo form_checkbox('requests[]' , '$mediator' , TRUE);
    foreach($mediator as $key => $val){
        echo $key . " : " . $val;
        echo "</br>";
    }
}
echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Approve Requests');
echo form_close();
?>
```

I want the array stored in $mediator to be passed into the value of corresponding check box. In the above mentioned code, it is storing literal '$mediator' in the value of the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to send an array, then you need to turn it into a string using JSON:

```
echo form_checkbox('requests[]' , json_encode($mediator) , TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But, then what do i do to so something like this : $mediator['id'] ?(if id is a key in the array)

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain better?

Comment: Actually, $mediator is an array like this: 'student_name' => 'Sam', 'id' => 1 etc. So how do i access the value of id key in the array?

Comment: Where do you want to access this? in the front-end(when creating yor HTML form)? or in the back-end(the php that catches your form's request)?

Comment: backend, i would return this to controller as: $data = $this->input->post('requests');

Comment: I think what would be best is if you show me what `$start` contains

Comment: $start contains n number of arrays each of which contains various fields like name, id etc and each of these fields has a value

Comment: see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
// sample $start data
$start = array(
    array(
        'id' => 20,
        'student_name' => 'Sam'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 18,
        'student_name' => 'John'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'student_name' => 'Bob'
    )
);

echo form_open('main/req_submit');
foreach ($start as $mediator) {
    echo form_checkbox('mediator_ids[]', $mediator['id'], TRUE);
    echo $mediator['student_name'] . "<br>";
}
echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Approve Requests');
echo form_close();
```

This will send a POST request like this:

```
array (size=2)
  'mediator_ids' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '20' (length=1)
      1 => string '18' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
  'mysubmit' => string 'Approve Requests' (length=16)
```

So then, your PHP can catch the IDs. You dont need to send the names.